# Feynman Propagator in presence of boundary terms

Tags: quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, propagator, klein-gordon-equation, boundary-terms

It is known that when a Klein-Gordon (KG) field is expressed in plane wave basis, then the Feynman propagator defined as

$$\Delta_F(x-y)=\langle 0|T\{\phi(x)\phi(y)\}|0\rangle$$
equals the Green's function for the KG Operator. However, we can take a different approach using the Schwinger-Dyson equations (see for instance $\S 7.1$ from  *Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model* by Matthew D. Schwartz). Using the shorthand notation $\langle\phi_1\phi_2\rangle$ for $\langle 0|T\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\}|0\rangle$ we can write
$$\langle\phi_1\phi_2\rangle=\int d^4x \;\delta_{x1}\langle\phi_x\phi_2\rangle=i\int d^4x \;\Box_xG_{x1}\langle\phi_x\phi_2\rangle$$
where we have $\Box_x G_{x1}=-i\delta_{x1}$. At this stage, we can naively do integration by parts and obtain $\langle\phi_1\phi_2\rangle=G_{12}$ in agreement with the first definition. However, if we keep the surface terms while performing by-parts we get
$$\langle\phi_1\phi_2\rangle=G_{12}+W_{12}-4\int d\sigma^a d\sigma'^b \partial_aG_{x1}\partial'_bG_{x'2}\langle\phi_x\phi_{x'}\rangle$$ where $$W_{12}=i\int d\sigma^a [G_{x1}\partial_a G_{x2}+(1\leftrightarrow 2)].$$ We can iteratively replace $\langle\phi_x\phi_{x'}\rangle$ with the above expression and obtain a polynomial of $G$ and it's derivatives. It is not clear whether all these additional terms combined should cancel out one another. And so my question is , what exactly went wrong in the first definition that we didn't get any of these surface terms?

I think the issue lies in the ansatz that the KG field can be written as superposition of plane waves. Intuitively, the plane waves $e^{ipx}$ should oscillate vigorously for large $x$ and cancel out one another and so the field should vanish near infinity where our boundary lies. And this is probably why Schwartz ignored the surface terms while doing integration by parts. However, the  second definition and the Schwinger-Dyson equation doesn't depend on the plane wave decomposition and therefore seems more reliable. So my 2nd question is how should we modify our ansatz for plane wave decomposition so that the two definitions of Feynman propagators agree?